# PowerShellの関数の作り方→引数がうまく渡らないみたいです．

Tags: powershell

PowerShellのお勉強中です．
バッチ処理で個々の処理の経過時間を出すために以下のようなコードを書きました．これはうまく動きます．

```
$start_date_time = Get-Date
# ここでそれなりに時間のかかる処理
$end_date_time = Get-Date
$time_span = New-TimeSpan -Start $start_date_time -End $end_date_time
Write-Host 'Processing takes' $time_span.Minutes 'minutes ' $time_span.Seconds 'seconds.' -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
```

結果

```
Processing takes 0 minutes  2 seconds.
```

関数を勉強したくて、試しに自分でモジュールを作って以下のような関数にしてみました．

```
function Get-TimeSpan{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.DateTime]$startTime
  )
  $end_date_time = Get-Date
  $time_span = New-TimeSpan -Start $startTime -End $end_date_time
  return $time_span
}
```

これを次のように呼び出します．

```
$start_date_time = Get-Date
# ここでそれなりに時間のかかる処理
$time_span = Get-TimeSpan -startTime $start_date_time
Write-Host 'Processing takes' $time_span.Minutes 'minutes ' $time_span.Seconds 'seconds.' -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor Black
```

ところがこれはエラーになってしまいます．

```
New-TimeSpan: Cannot bind parameter 'Start' to the target. Exception setting "Start": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
```

引数がうまく渡っていないように見えるのですが、いったいどこが悪いのでしょうか？
すみませんがご教示ください．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

［追記］
PSVersionTableによるバージョン/環境は以下のとおりです．

```
PS D:\My_Documents\XML2020\XXXXXX\docs\xml-php> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.22000
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コードに問題はないようです。
こちらの環境で質問のコードをそのままコピー＆ペーストしたところ正常に動作しました。
スクリプトに書いて実行してみましたが結果は同じく正常でした。

環境の問題ではないでしょうか。
こちらの環境は以下です。

- 実行環境のWindowsのバージョン
  エディション  Windows 10 Pro
  バージョン   21H1
  インストール日 ‎2021/‎12/‎18
  OS ビルド  19043.1415
  エクスペリエンス    Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
- PowerShellのバージョン($PSVersionTable)
  PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1320

【追記】
次のバージョンでも結果は同じです。正常に動作します。
7.2.1

```
PS C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Comment: 検証ありがとうございました．私のVSCodeのPowerShellのPSVersionTableによる動作環境を質問の後に追記いたしました．

Comment: VSCodeのターミナルでも実行してみましたが、問題の現象は発生しませんでした。どこが違っているのでしょうね。実行環境のWindowsのバージョンはいくつでしょうか。

Comment: Setting > System > Aboutで見ますと、Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 21H2
Installed on ‎2021/‎11/‎04
OS build 22000.376
Serial number XXXXXXXX
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.376.0 になります．

Comment: 失礼しました．フォルダに以前のVSCodeの設定（？）が残存していて影響を与えていたようです．".ionide"というフォルダを削除したらなんの問題もなく動いてくれました．

Comment: 解決してなりよりです。